# What is String Table in C?

Tags: c, pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

```
char *p = "one two three";
```

Apparently, the string constant in this code is stored in the string table. What is "string table"? Is it in the *heap* or on the *stack*?

Information Background: I found this info in 
[Teach Yourself C, by Hilbert Schildt](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0078823110), at chapter 6 (Using Pointers).

> As you know, C allows string constants enclosed between double quotes to be used in a program. When compiler encounters such a string, it stores it in the program's string table and generates a pointer to the string. For this reason, the following program is correct and prints - one two three.
>
> ```
> #include<stdio.h>
> int main(void){
>   char*p = "one two three";
>   printf(p);
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: _Is it in the heap or stack?_ They are usually placed at the `.rodata` section (read only - stack). OT: always use a format specifier with `printf`: `printf(p);` --> `printf("%s", p);`

Comment: "String table" is not a C-language concept.  Neither are "stack" or "heap", for that matter, but those are at least applied fairly commonly to C, and they correspond to characteristics of most C implementations.  Not so much "string table".

Comment: Schildt is a *notoriously* bad authority on C; he’s a decent writer, but he constantly mangles basic concepts.  He also assumes you’re working on a Windows platform and conflates Windows-specific terms and concepts with those of the basic language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the cited paragraph means, is a separated section of your program. These string constants are neither in the stack nor on the heap.

Think about these kinds of sections a program may use to store stuff (common names of sections defined in the executable's file format in parentheses):

- The machine code to execute (`.text`);
- Static read-only values, for example `static const` variables (`.rodata`);
- Static read-write variables with non-zero initial values (`.data`);
- Static read-write variables with zero'ed initial values (`.bss`);
- The stack to hold return addresses, function parameters, local variables, and so on; sometimes these are separated;
- The heap, if there is one at all.

String constants commonly fall in the category "static read-only values". Some compiler systems separate them from non-string values.

Any compiler system may have these sections or not, but they are quite common.

Anyway, abstract from this implementation detail. It will only help you if you need to go that deep, and you need to know how your specific compiler system works.

On the abstract level, we can differentiate two cases:

#### `const char* p = "one two three";`

The string constant is stored *somewhere*, and its address is assigned to `p`. If you overwrite this variable with another value, you will lose the address.

An extra space is needed for the variable `p`. Where this is, depends on the variable.

#### `const char a[] = "one two three";`

The string constant is stored *somewhere*, too. The array is allocated at this place. As long as `a` is visible, you can access its characters.

**Final note**: Characters of a string constant are read-only. Always declare your respective variable with `const char`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible levels of answer here:

1. what is mandated by the language
2. how it is commonly implemented

[@thebusybee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68601736/3545273) focuses on the second point, I will focus on the first.

Stack and heap do not exist on a language point of view: they are only implementation details, and some old implementations used more than one heap (local heap # global heap). The language only defines duration:

- static duration: the lifetime is the lifetime of the program
- dynamic duration: the lifetime starts after allocation with `malloc` and ends with `free`
- automatic: the lifetime starts at the beginning of the bloc where the variable is declared and ends at the end of the bloc.

A string litteral (enclosed in double quotes) is a *constant*. That means that trying to modify it invokes Undefined Behaviour and that the constant lifetime is the duration of the program. If you use more than once the same string litteral, it is unspecified whether they will have same address or not:

```
const char *p = "abc";
...
const char *q = "abc"; // p == q may be true or false
```

Beware, a string litteral can also be used to initialize an array:

```
char s[] = "abc";    // array initialization
```

Here `s` is a true array (and can be modified because it is not declared to be `const`), and depending how it is declared it can have automatic or static duration. Whether the string litteral has an existance *per se* (independant of the array) is again an implementation detail.